# Finding value of nodes using XMLDOm in PHP

Tags: php, xpath, xmldom

I need to extract information from an XML using XMLDom.

Below is **myroot.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<myroot xml:lang='en'>
<delta>
    <history>
        <detail>
            <id>one</id>
            <degree>
                <dname>alpha</dname>
                <dates>
                    <StartDate>
                        <Year>1998</Year>
                    </StartDate>
                    <EndDate>
                        <Year>2002</Year>
                    </EndDate>
                </dates>
            </degree>
        </detail>
        <detail>
            <id>two</id>
            <degree>
                <dname>beta</dname>
                <dates>
                    <StartDate>
                        <Year>2006</Year>
                    </StartDate>
                    <EndDate>
                        <Year>2008</Year>
                    </EndDate>
                </dates>
            </degree>
        </detail>
    </history>
</delta>
```

here is my code

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$rootxmldoc = $doc->load('myroot.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($rootxmldoc);
$items = $hrxml_obj->getElementsByTagName("detail");
$subitemarray = array();
$icounter = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $query = "//dates/*/Year"; //xpath of all occurrence of Year
    $entries = $xpath->query($query, $item);
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
      $dates["startdate"] = "todo"; //extract StartDate
      $dates["enddate"] = "todo";  //extract EndDate
    }
    $subitemarray[$icounter++] = dates;
}
var_dump($subitemarray);
```

Ideally I need to extract dates using xpath. I am not able to get this nailed. any help is appreciated. The issue is the usage of xpath while looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XPath go directly to yout `dates` tag, and then use [`DOMElement::getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php) to get `StartDate` and `EndDate` (you can also go to the `dates` tag using [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php), but XPath gives you more flexibility should you need it). This will return a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), but you know (if the structure is constant) that you only need the first element of the list. So:

```
// $xml ommited, saved in a variable for testing purposes
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName("detail");
$subitemarray = array();
$icounter = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $query = "//dates"; //xpath of all occurrence of Year
    $entries = $xpath->query($query, $item);
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        $startDate = $entry->getElementsByTagName("StartDate")[0]->nodeValue;
        $endDate = $entry->getElementsByTagName("EndDate")[0]->nodeValue;
        $dates["startdate"] = $startDate; //extract StartDate
        $dates["enddate"] = $endDate;  //extract EndDate
    }
    $subitemarray[$icounter++] = $dates;
}
var_dump($subitemarray);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/7bE9n)

Or only with XPath:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName("detail");
$subitemarray = array();
$icounter = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $queryStart = "//dates/StartDate";
    $entriesStart = $xpath->query($queryStart, $item);
    $dates["startdate"] = $entriesStart[0]->nodeValue;

    $queryEnd = "//dates/EndDate";
    $entriesEnd = $xpath->query($queryEnd, $item);
    $dates["enddate"] = $entriesEnd[0]->nodeValue;
    $subitemarray[$icounter++] = $dates;
}
var_dump($subitemarray);
```

And lastly, using only one XPath query:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName("detail");
$subitemarray = array();
$icounter = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $query = "//dates/*[contains(local-name(), 'Date')]
";
    $entries = $xpath->query($query, $item);
    $dates["startdate"] = $entries[0]->nodeValue;
    $dates["enddate"] = $entries[1]->nodeValue;
    $subitemarray[$icounter++] = $dates;
}
var_dump($subitemarray);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Aie3G)

The query will simply get any elements inside the current `detail` element that contains the word "Date". Again, if the structure is constant, you can assume that the first result will be `StartDate` and the second result will be `EndDate`.

Comment: What do you mean? @user4826347

Comment: Your second option looks good to me but is not working for me.... not sure why it is not behaving as expected

Comment: Could you elaborate? What’s the output? Did the first or third examples work for you?

Comment: no output for second option. Third example is what gets working. but i prefer a direct xpath than using contains.